# In GAE standard environment for nodejs and ruby, IAP returns 403. What are the possible causes?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, in-app-purchase

In GAE standard environment, IAP returns 403. What are the possible causes?

I have no clue, so let me ask.

When I set GAE to flexible environment, I can pass IAP, but when I set it to standard environment, it returns 403.
The instance takes 10 to 20 seconds to launch, but it returns 403 even with a running instance.
GAE uses Cloud load balancer, and IAP is configured for serverless NEG.

What are the possible causes?

---

Update:

<s>It seems that the problem is caused by the combination of LB's URL Map and GAE's Standard environment.
Do you have a workaround for this?</s>

---

Update: 2021-05-06

The problem was simple.

It just didn't work in the standard environment runtime for nodejs and ruby, but it worked in the standard environment runtime for python2 and python3.

How to try it.

```sh
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples
cd nodejs-docs-samples/appengine/hello-world/standard/
gcloud app deploy
-> 403

git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples.git
cd python-docs-samples/appengine/standard/users/
gcloud app deploy
-> 200 OK

git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples.git
cd python-docs-samples/appengine/standard_python3/hello_world/
gcloud app deploy
-> 200 OK
```

I can't find any documentation on this, but I was wondering if anyone knows?

Comment: If you access to GAE without the load balancer, do you have the same issue? And how do you access to the GAE, through the browser or direct access (curl, api call)?

Comment: The HTTP Status Code of 403 means "Forbidden" - The request contained valid data and was understood by the server, but the server is refusing action. This seems to be an authorization access issue.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
The same event occurred with no load balancer and only one default service in the standard environment in GAE.
I may have made a mistake in my configuration. I will keep looking into it.

Comment: The text has been updated.